# Highlight nbsp character in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: text, syntax-highlighting, whitespace, sublimetext2

Is there a way to highlight special whitespace characters like nbsp in Sublime Text 2? Several times I copied text from word users to my code and it crashed because I couldn't see these "illegal" whitespace characters...

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plugin for Sublime Text that does the job:
https://github.com/possan/sublime_unicode_nbsp

You can comment out lines 125 and 126 if the highlighting of trailing whitespaces annoys you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your user settings as below (you may go into "`Preferences->Settings Default.`" or "`Preferences->Setting User.`" depends on whether you've already had some customized settings) :

```
{
    "color_scheme": ...,
    "font_size": ...,
    "draw_white_space": "$your_selection"
}
```

The rule to set the setting is:

1. Set to "none" to turn off drawing white space
2. Set to a list to draw only the white space within the list
3. Set to "all" to draw all white space

Comment: `"draw_white_space": [" "] ` has no effect in ST3